# Entity Framework - could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Boolean'

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have a Sql View that we are using with Entity Framework and Ria Services. When I get the view

```
var _entity = _context.DepthChartViews;
```

the _entity is always empty and I get this error.

The 'IsPrimary' property on 'DepthChartView' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Boolean'.

My view has this set as a bool - my data is either a 1 or a 0 - i dont have this being set anywhere in code - it is always a true / false.

Been debugging this for a bit and cannot seem to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Find the IsPrimary property in your .edmx, either via the GUI tool in Visual Studio or in the .edmx file XML itself. You can set the GUI view to also show types as well as property names in your Entities: it is a right click option. It sounds like the Entity Model thinks the property is a string for some reason so the mapping is screwed up...you need to tell it that its a non-nullable bool.